# jQuery Validation Plugin, declaring required rules with attributes is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Using jQuery version 1.4.2 and Validation plugin version 1.8.1

I have a textbox that is required only if a checkbox is checked.
If I declare the rule in the validation method it works flawless:

```
$("#tipoEntradasForm").validate({
    rules: {
        cantidad_aforo: { required: "#aforo_limitado:checked" }
    }
})
```

but for the sake of simplicity, I need to declare it in an attribute on the input tag.

I tried several variations, all of them something like

```
<input
    name="cantidad_aforo" id="cantidad_aforo" type="text" 
    class="anchofecha"
    required="#aforo_limitado:checked"
    min="1"
    value="" 
/>
```

but with no success.

Can anybody tell me if I am doing something wrong and what should I do instead? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input's attribute 'required' is not the same thing as the jquery validation's method. So you can't do it like this.
So the original code is the simpliest way to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<input type="text" name="cantidad_aforo" id="cantidad_aforo" class="{ required: "#aforo_limitado:checked" }" min="1" value="" />`

Comment: I was hopping that it would work, but it is not working on chrome. I was almost sure that it was possible !

Comment: This might be silly but did you checked quotes? <input type="text" name="cantidad_aforo" id="cantidad_aforo" class="{ required: '#aforo_limitado:checked' }" min="1" value="" />

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. I even look into the validation source code and I discovered a line that reads `if (this in $.validator.classRuleSettings)` (line 789 version 1.9.0) where `this` takes the form of the words in the class attribute, and classRuleSettings is a map with entries like: `required: {required: true}`, so... if a word match a rule, it is added to the rules array with defaults values. I think that I could create my own customRule add it to classRuleSettings and then use the new rule or something like that.